# Storing URLs in an SQL database

Tags: php, sql

Ive seen this question about but can't seem to find a solution for me.

I have a simple database for storing/viewing contact details and I want to store a lot of URLs for each contact.

edit: I've revised my script now, here s the code I'm now using:
The html form:

```
<title>DDD Artist Entry</title>

<link href="/ddd/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div align="center"> <!-- main centre -->

<p></p>
<p>Add a new artists details here</p>
<p></p>

<table class="main_page extra_pad border" width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">The Basics</td>
        <td>
<form name="newent" id="newent" method="post" action="newent_handle.php">

<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" required="required"></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" required="required"></p>
<p>Alias: <input type="text" name="alias"></p>
<p>E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" size="32" required="required"></p>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Social Media</td>
        <td>

<p>PayPal Email: <input type="email" name="ppemail" size="32"></p>
<p>Website: <input type="text" name="website" size="64"></p>
<p>F.B. Name: <input type="text" name="fbident" size="64"></p>
<p>F.B. Fan Page: <input type="text" name="fb_fanpage" size="64"></p>
<p>Twitter: <input type="text" name="twitter" size="64"></p>
<p>Soundcloud: <input type="text" name="soundcloud" size="64"></p>
<p>MySpace: <input type="text" name="myspace" size="64"></p>
<p>HearThis: <input type="text" name="hearthis" size="64"></p>
<p>YouTube: <input type="text" name="youtube" size="64"></p>
<p>BeatPort: <input type="text" name="beatport" size="64"></p>
<p>Instagram: <input type="text" name="instagram" size="64"></p>
<p>ReverbNation: <input type="text" name="reverbnation" size="64"></p>
<p>Tumblr: <input type="text" name="tumblr" size="64"></p>
<p>BandCamp: <input type="text" name="bandcamp" size="64"></p>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">

<!-- <p>Comments: <input type="text" name="comments"></p> -->

<p align="center"><input name="enter" type="submit" value="Put them in!">
</form></p>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</div><!-- main centre -->

</body>
</html>
```

Now here's the handler script it passes to

```
<?PHP

// ------- DDD new artist entry HANDLER SCRIPT -------

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pw", "db") or die(mysqli_error());

// Let's get the text from the form, we escape string for anti-sql-injection. Nice.

$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
$alias = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['alias']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$ppemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ppemail']);
$website = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['website']);
$fbident = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fbident']);
$fb_fanpage = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fb_fanpage']);
$twitter = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['twitter']);
$soundcloud = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['soundcloud']);
$myspace = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['myspace']);
$youtube = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['youtube']);
$hearthis = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['hearthis']);
$beatport = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['beatport']);
$instagram = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['instagram']);
$reverbnation = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['reverbnation']);
$tumblr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tumblr']);
$bandcamp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bandcamp']);
//$comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comments']);

// insert the appropriate records

$artist_insert = "INSERT INTO artists";
$artist_insert.= " (artist_fname,";     // 1
$artist_insert.= " artist_lname,";       // 2
$artist_insert.= " artist_alias,";       // 3
$artist_insert.= " artist_email,";       // 4
$artist_insert.= " artist_ppemail,";      // 5
$artist_insert.= " artist_website,";      // 6
$artist_insert.= " artist_fbident,";       // 7
$artist_insert.= " artist_fb_fanpage,"; // 8
$artist_insert.= " artist_twitter,";       // 9
$artist_insert.= " artist_soundcloud,"; // 10
$artist_insert.= " artist_myspace,";       // 11
$artist_insert.= " artist_youtube,";       // 12
$artist_insert.= " artist_hearthis,";     // 13
$artist_insert.= " artist_beatport,";     // 14
$artist_insert.= " artist_instagram,";   // 15
$artist_insert.= " artist_reverbnation,"; // 16
$artist_insert.= " artist_tumblr,";     // 17
$artist_insert.= " artist_bandcamp,";     // 18
$artist_insert.= " artist_date)";         // 19

$artist_insert.= " VALUES";
$artist_insert.= " ('$fname',";       // 1
$artist_insert.= " '$lname',";       // 2
$artist_insert.= " '$alias',";        // 3
$artist_insert.= " '$email',";       // 4
$artist_insert.= " '$ppemail',";      // 5
$artist_insert.= " '$website',";       // 6
$artist_insert.= " '$fbident',";       // 7
$artist_insert.= " '$fb_fanpage',"; // 8
$artist_insert.= " '$twitter',";       // 9
$artist_insert.= " '$soundcloud',"; // 10
$artist_insert.= " '$myspace',";       // 11
$artist_insert.= " '$youtube',";       // 12
$artist_insert.= " '$hearthis',";     // 13
$artist_insert.= " '$beatport',";     // 14
$artist_insert.= " '$instagram',";   // 15
$artist_insert.= " '$reverbnation',"; // 16
$artist_insert.= " '$tumblr',";     // 17
$artist_insert.= " '$bandcamp',";     // 18
$artist_insert.= " NOW())";         // 19

var_dump($artist_insert);
die();

?>
```

The problem:

I can fill in the form with fname, lname, alias, email and ppemail, and also an http web address in the first 'website' box and my var_dump gives me an sql statement. However, if I fill in the above details and put a sectond http address in the next box too I then get an error which reads:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /ddd/newent_handle.php on this
>   server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I've spoken to my server people many times now and they say all my permissions are set ok. There is also nothing appearing in my server error log.

Curiously I can fill in the entire form with random keystroke test data and it will work but I keep getting this error when I try it with web addresses.
To make things more crazy, it will work with a single web address in the 'website' field, or the youtube field, but not the beatport field or certain others.

The script seems so simple I'm about to go spare.
Can anyone see or suggest anything?
Much appreciated.

Comment: Are all these values required, or can they be empty? You should also not use the `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli_*` instead. I really would switch to using the `mysqli` or `PDO` class with parameterized queries so you don't have to escape everything, since your code is really messy.

Comment: some of the firelds may be empty yes, not all required.
re: messy old code yes sorry it's been a long time since I did this last!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create another table like `social_links` so you don't store this many `NULL` records.

Comment: Maybe, I'm not quite sure how that would work as I'm pretty rubbish with databases :) and was just trying to get this system to work first before I considered any tweaks. I'm sure that's not the attitude haha but it's only a small amount of data I need to store just now

Comment: Can you paste the generated sql here?

Comment: I could but I'm not sure how!

Comment: I would also pass your connection as the second parameter to the `mysql_real_escape_string` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124989/discussion-between-mr-c-and-thomas).

Comment: `var_dump($artist_insert);` before you execute the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha! So I got this response from my server people at last:

> Thank you for your reply and for providing that information. I have
>   gone ahead and replicated the error you were getting. It looks like
>   it's due to ModSecurity. I'll be escalating this ticket up to our
>   second line techs to see if an exception can be made.

It troubles me I should have to have an exception made, but hey if it works.

Edit: It's finally fixed, and for reference here is what they did:

> I've added to mod-security rules. The rules are 340163 and 340163. You
>   can learn more about these rules.
>
> https://wiki.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/WAF_340162
>
> Most of these rules work well but occasionally some pages get tripped
>   incorrectly so we add an exception.